# Disabling items in ListView with graphical effect

Tags: android

I want to disable items in a `ListView`.

First, I tried to use the method `isEnabled()` from my `ArrayAdapter`. 

But this method is used to make a difference between seperators an normal list view items.

So I tried to disable my items by setting the `OnClickListener` and `OnLongClickListener` to `NULL` in the method `getView()` of my `ArrayAdapter`. 

This works, but has no graphical effect to the disabled item.

Do I have to set the graphical effect by myself or are there better ways to disable an item in a `ListView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the solution for my question: List items are disabled by layout. Simply add `android:clickable="true"` (yes, `true` is right) to the root node of the layout. To add an graphical effect to the elements of the list item (e.g. TextViews), simply add `android:enabled="false"` to them. At last you have to inflate this "disabled" layout in your list view adapter. That's all :-)